# Installer .pkg from terminal fails to APFS volume

Tags: macos, terminal, installer, macos-highsierra, apfs

Had a .pkg I've been installing from command line to various systems for ages with no problem, recently noticed it's been failing with the following error message:

> Cannot install on volume /Volumes/Macintosh HD because it is disabled

Noticed this is happening only on APFS formatted volumes.

The package can install from the GUI just fine, so I'm not sure if it's issue with APFS - it's obviously a bug, but does anyone know a workaround or another way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the .pkg needed recreating for APFS to specifically allow it to be installed to "other volumes" - HFS didn't seem to care about this.